# How to create new string type in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, types

I need to create new class - myType. I want to add String items to the `List<Object>`as myType.
Example (it isn't correct, but it can explain what I need):

```
ArrayList<Object> attemptList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            attemptList.add(Sting.toMyType("Loading time"));
```

I have:

```
class myType {
        private String type;

        public myType() {
            type = new String();
        }
        public myType toMyType(String string) {
            type.**????**
            return(this);
        }
    }
```

As I understand, I need to create toString analog in the toMyType?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: uh... why not `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do, to be honest.

Comment: this ArrayList will be Xstreamed to the XML and I want to add aliases to rename each myType class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own class, that contains the `String` object, and override the `toString()` method, so that when printing out your object, you get the contained string, such as this.

```
private class MyClass() {

    public String innerString;

    public MyClass(String s) {
        innerString = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return innerString.toString();
    }
}
```

However, this would make little sense, other that effectively renaming the class. Furthermore, if you wanted to use string operations over the string, you would have to call the method over `innerString` field. For example:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass("test string");
a.innerString.substring(0,5);
```

All other `String` methods can be overridden, similarly as `toString()`, but if this is what you need, I would suggest rethinking your approach, as reimplementing existing classes hints to design problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but:

```
ArrayList<MyType> attemptList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
            attemptList.add(new MyType("Loading time"));


class MyType {
        private String type;

        public myType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Now you can construct a `MyType` containing a `String`, you can query the `String`, and you can add the `MyType`s to the `List`.

For streaming to XML in most XML conversion libraries you can use annotations or configuration to tell the XML library how to map each field. Just use a simple String in Java, and then configure the mapping appropriately. Don't butcher your Java code just to do the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pretend that an instance of your string-like type is a `String`, or vice versa.

And `String` is a `final` class, so you cannot create subclasses.

And, for the record, there are sound reasons why it would be **bad** if you could do either of those things ...

Probably, the closest you can come to doing what you want to do is to create a custom type of `CharSequence` ... and rely on the fact that a lot of standard APIs accept a `CharSequence` rather than a `String`.  Or maybe you should just make your custom type a String holder type ... like @TimB illustrates with his answer.

---

Based on your last comment and your previous Questions, I think that what you actually need to do is to implement an Xstream [Converter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) for your `ArrayList<String>`.  Or maybe you could do it using Xstream [Annotations](http://xstream.codehaus.org/annotations-tutorial.html).  Certainly hacking your application's types to make the XML look nice seems the wrong approach.

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet.  It is NOT clear from your example what you are hoping to achieve.  I've just made some assumptions and covered some obvious possibilities.